# Memory allocation in stack

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int i, j;
    int *p = &i;    
            
    cout << "Address of i = " << &i << endl;
    cout << "Address of j = " << &j << ", which is " << &i - 1 << endl;
    cout << "Address of p = " << &p << ", which is NOT " << &j - 1 << endl;
}
```

and I got the following output (VS Code, with GCC):

```
Address of i = 0x61fe1c
Address of j = 0x61fe18, which is 0x61fe18
Address of p = 0x61fe10, which is NOT 0x61fe14
```

I thought local variables, like int or pointer, are allocated *continuously* in the stack. So I am expecting

```
Address of i = 0x61fe1c
Address of j = 0x61fe18
Address of p = 0x61fe14
```

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I think I got it. The pointer points to the lower address of the variable.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int i, j;
    int *p;
    int k, x;
            
    cout << "Address of i = " << &i << endl;
    cout << "Address of j = " << &j << ", which is " << &p + 1 << endl;
    cout << "Address of p = " << &p << ", which is " << &k + 1 << endl;
    cout << "Address of k = " << &k << ", which is " << &x + 1 << endl;     
}
```

This gives me

```
Address of i = 0x61fe1c
Address of j = 0x61fe18, which is 0x61fe18
Address of p = 0x61fe10, which is 0x61fe10
Address of k = 0x61fe0c, which is 0x61fe0c
```

as expected.

Comment: Is there a reason the actual memory addresses where your variables are being stored matters to you?

Comment: Here's a hint: On your machine, `sizeof(int) == 4`, and `sizeof(int*) == 8`

Comment: *I thought local variables, like int or pointer, are allocated continuously in the stack* -- Where did you get this (false) information?

Comment: I think it is *undefined behavior* to do the `&i - 1` and `&j - 1`.  Probably not important for the discussion at hand and for this small program.  But not something that should go into production code.

Comment: The stack itself is continuous. But the compiler can has no obligation to put the variables you declare in a particular order onto the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not really *missing* anything, as such, but your expectation has little basis.

Most compilers will typically use what's called "natural alignment", which means the size of the item is also its required alignment. For example, if you allocate a 4-byte item, it'll be allocated at an address that's a multiple of 4. Likewise, an 8-byte item, it'll be at an address that's a multiple of 8.

In some cases, alignment is even stricter than that, so (for example) a 16-byte item might need to be aligned to an address that's a multiple of 32. This is particularly common for "vectored" types, that hold multiple operands in a single large chunk, and operate on the multiple operands simultaneously (e.g., Intel AVX, or PowerPC Altivec).

So for example, if I have something like:

```cpp
int main() { 
    char x;
    int y;
}
```

My *usual* expectation would be to see either 3 or 7 unused bytes between `x` and `y` (3 bytes of padding if sizeof(int) == 4, 7 bytes if sizeof(int) == 8). That's not strictly required, but so common that it would be somewhat surprising if it didn't happen.

But regardless of the exact reasoning, the compiler is allowed to insert padding between local variables as it sees fit. In some cases (especially for debugging) they can/will insert extra space and fill it with known values. Then during exit from the routine, they'll check that those values remain intact, to give reasonable assurance that your code hasn't written to memory it shouldn't.